# Qt creator error on qtquickcontrolsapplication.h

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i have downloaded Qt creator 5.4 community edition from qt.io and installed on ubuntu 12.04 along with Qt designer. when i run the calendar example it gives out this error:

`/home/user/calendar/src/main.cpp:43: error: qtquickcontrolsapplication.h: No such file or directory`

by the way I have set qmlviewer and qmlscene in enviornment setting:

[image]

Comment: Does QtCreator see your compiler and the qt libraries? ie, is everything correct in the "Build & Run" page of Options?

Comment: yes it compiles simple qt desktop apps, but not qml applications

Comment: It looks that you compile or run QtProject with already existing in Ubuntu Qt version, not with new installed one

Comment: i removed the previous kit from setting and built a new project, but the same error occurs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the file bellow to the project path, i.e, the path where the ".pro" file is:

```
  /opt/Qt5.4.1/Examples/Qt-5.4/quick/controls/shared/qtquickcontrolsapplication.h
```

where **/opt/Qt5.4.1** is the directory where you installed the Qt SDK (aka QDIR).

The "copy example" procedure don't work for a lot of QML examples.

They all make relative path references to common files inside the SDK environment.

In this case, the ".pro" file shows:

```
include("../../controls/shared/shared.pri")
```

I made a symbolic link to locate this file from the project path, but it didn't work.

In this case, copying the files solved the problem.

Good luck!